# jQuery : change <div> Background on .change() of a select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I am trying to change the background image of a div-element when .change() of a select input fires, but I don't get it to work. As you can see in my code, I tried to dynamically change the background images of my 2 div elements as soon the parent dive gets selected in my select input.

Heres my code :

```js
$(window).bind('setup', function() {
  $(".abo-forms div").hide();
  $(".active-form").show();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).trigger('setup');
  $("#abo-weekday").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(".abo-forms div").hide();
    $(".abo-forms div").removeClass("active-form");
    $("#" + val + "Form").addClass("active-form");
    $(".active-form").show();
    var menu1 = "../img/" + val + "menu1.jpg";
    var menu2 = "../img/" + val + "menu2.jpg";
    $('.menu1').css('background-image', 'url(' + menu1 + ')');
    $('.menu2').css('background-image', 'url(' + menu2 + ')');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu1,
.menu2 {
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="abo-menu">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    <select id="abo-weekday">
      <option value="monday">Monday</option>
      <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
      <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
      <option value="friday">Friday</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="abo-forms">
  <div id="mondayForm" class="active-form small-12 columns">
    <div class="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu2"></div>
    Monday menu
  </div>
  <div id="tuesdayForm" class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu2"></div>
    Tuesday menu
  </div>
  <div id="wednesdayForm" class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu2"></div>
    Wednesday menu
  </div>
  <div id="thursdayForm" class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu2"></div>
    Thursday menu
  </div>
  <div id="fridayForm" class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu2"></div>
    Firday menu
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself.

I had to declare my path as the following :

```
var menu1 = "./img/" + val + 'menu1.jpg';
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$(".abo-forms div")` is hiding the `menu1` and `menu2` elements also. You can tune the selector to hide only the direct children of `abo-forms`.

```js
$(window).bind('setup', function() {
  $(".abo-forms > div").hide();
  $(".active-form").show();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).trigger('setup');
  $("#abo-weekday").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var a = $(".abo-forms > div").hide();
    $(".abo-forms > div.active-form").removeClass("active-form");
    $("#" + val + "Form").addClass("active-form").show();
    //changed for demo
    var menu1 = "//placehold.it/200/fff000?text=" + val + '-m1';
    var menu2 = "//placehold.it/200/fff000?text=" + val + '-m2';
    $('.menu1').css('background-image', 'url(' + menu1 + ')');
    $('.menu2').css('background-image', 'url(' + menu2 + ')');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu1,
.menu2 {
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="abo-menu">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    <select id="abo-weekday">
      <option value="monday">Monday</option>
      <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
      <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
      <option value="friday">Friday</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="abo-forms">
  <div id="mondayForm" class="active-form small-12 columns">
    <div class="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu2"></div>
    Monday menu
  </div>
  <div id="tuesdayForm" class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu2"></div>
    Tuesday menu
  </div>
  <div id="wednesdayForm" class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu2"></div>
    Wednesday menu
  </div>
  <div id="thursdayForm" class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu2"></div>
    Thursday menu
  </div>
  <div id="fridayForm" class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu2"></div>
    Firday menu
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mhm your snippet works, but @ my phone or my browsers locally i am still not seeing the pictures. :/

Answer (score 0):

In .menu1, .menu2 classes you gave display property as inline. If there is no content in that particular element the width and height property will be 0px.
Change the display inline to inline-block it will work fine. 
$(".abo-forms div") is hiding the menu1 and menu2 elements change that.
[Please refer this link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Comment: Tried that after Arun postet his fix.

Comment: Works for Weblinks but not locally. :/ so another problem seems to be here :

        var menu1 = "../img/" + val + 'menu1.jpg';
        var menu2 = "../img/" + val + 'menu2.jpg';
        $('.menu1').css('background-image', 'url(' + menu1 + ')');
        $('.menu2').css('background-image', 'url(' + menu2 + ')');

Comment: Have you read the link that i shared.? inline elements will not accept width and height

Comment: Yes i read it, and i changed display : inline to display : inline-block. This solution was also provided by Arun before and it works. But it only works when I set my menu1 and menu2 variables to weblinks like Arun did for demo. But with my local images in my img folder it doens't work. :/